# How can we ping an internet ip with a specific routing table

Tags: networking, ip, routing, ping

I have a routing table v1

```
default via 192.168.199.1 dev eth0
192.168.199.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.199.6
```

and routing table v2 as

```
default via 192.168.198.1 dev eth1
192.168.198.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.198.6
```

I want to ping 8.8.8.8 from table v1 by eth0 interface and use table v2 for eth1 interface.

Comment: If eth1's network mask is set to 192.168.199.0/24, then nothing that begins with anything other than 192.168.199.X can ever be reached out of it.  The default route you put on eth1 will not ever work.  Was this a typo?  Also - I know where you are probably going with this, read this: https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/29/a-quick-introduction-to-linux-policy-routing/

Comment: I am really sorry, typing mistake

Comment: Using ubuntu - ping is using main routing table not my custom table even setting -I eth0 didnt work

Comment: Maybe this could help too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30408/how-to-ping-use-specific-network-card

Comment: I have already tried this answer but it's not working